# Failed transaction due to Internal JSON-RPC

Tags: solidity

I’m experiencing an error while trying to transfer a coin on Binance smart chain using MetaMask . The is error is Internal JSON-RPC error. What could be the issue on the smart contract?

I tried sending a con from one wallet to another

Comment: please share your error message along with the source code